# PostgreSQL : converting existing double precision column to integer data type

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in PostgreSQL that contains numbers. The column's data type is double precision, and the numbers have a lot of decimal digits. I don't need that level of accuracy. Integers would be enough.

How do I redefine the column as having an integer datatype, while rounding the current existing data to obtain integers ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just alter the table, Postgres will automatically cast the double values to integer by rounding the appropriately:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN some_column TYPE integer;
```

This will essentially do the same as:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN some_data TYPE integer 
   USING round(some_data)::integer;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ea3c/1

Comment: Tried this and get "ERROR:  integer out of range". Perhaps because there are some null values in the column ? They should just remain null.

Comment: @SLeon: then you need to use `bigint` instead of `integer`

Comment: `bigint` won't necessarily work either, `select 1e100::bigint` for example.